# Connection Refused while deploying sentry server in Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, sentry

Am using python sentry server for tracking logs of my website.And i have used nginx server to deploy it, my servers IP is xx.xx.xx.xx when i open this in browser it shows me **502 Bad Gateway** and when i checked the log it shows

"**connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to  upstream**".

Below is configuration i have used in NGINX ,

```
log_format timed_combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe';

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx ;
    root /srv/www/name-sentry;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 default ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/xx.xx.xx.xx/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/xx.xx.xx.xx/ssl.key;

    ssl_ciphers '';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains";

    keepalive_timeout 0;
    # CHANGE ME: long timeout for ERP POST images
    proxy_read_timeout 200;
    proxy_send_timeout 200;

    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx ;
    root /srv/www/name-sentry;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/name-sentry-access.log timed_combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/name-sentry-error.log;
    error_page 502 /502.html;
    error_page 503 /503.html;
    error_page 504 /504.html;


    try_files $uri @name-sentry;


    location / {

        proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
        #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
        #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
        #add_header X-Backend-Server $hostname;
    }
}
```

NOTE: xx.xx.xx.xx--is my IP.Command to start sentry server is "sentry start" and it works and sentry uses 9000 port.What is the solution of this ?

Comment: Does your sentry server use port 80?

Comment: @julivico foregot to specify sentry uses 9000 port by default

Comment: `proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9000;` instead of `proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx;`?

Comment: @julivico tried that no luck